# google maps flex API: handle both double and single clicks?

Tags: apache-flex, google-maps, gis

how do you tell a single mouse click from a double click? my single
click listener seems to be trapping all the double clicks as well:

[tz locator](http://www.sustainablegis.com/projects/tz/tzMap/)

it's a known issue for the flash/flex API but the js workaround doesn't seem to handle both either: [code.google.com](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=394)

Answer (score 1):

Might need a bit of clarification, but make sure you are using the Google Map's MapMouseEvent, not the Flash API's click events (please assume this code in inside a `Map` subclass):

```
public class GoogleMap extends Map 
{
    import com.google.maps.LatLng;
    import com.google.maps.Map;
    import com.google.maps.MapEvent;
    import com.google.maps.MapMouseEvent;

    public function GoogleMap():void
    {
        super();
        this.key = "YOUR_API_KEY";

        addEventListener(MapEvent.MAP_READY, _onMapReady);
        addEventListener(MapMouseEvent.CLICK, _onMapClick);
        addEventListener(MapMouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK, _onMapDoubleClick);
    }

    protected function _onMapClick(event:MapMouseEvent):void 
    {  
        trace("single!");
        var mousePoint:Point = new Point(mouseX, mouseY);
        var mousePointLocal:Point = globalToLocal(mousePoint);
        var mouseLatLng:LatLng = this.fromViewportToLatLng(mousePointLocal); 
    }

    protected function _onMapDoubleClick(event:MapMouseEvent):void 
    {
        trace("double!");
    }

    protected function _onMapReady(event:MapEvent):void 
    {
        trace("ready!")
    }
}
```